# Network GUI tools for Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, networking, gui, raspberry-pi

I'm a Windows user trying to figure out Linux and the Raspberry Pi.  While I have always applauded the [Unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy#Do_One_Thing_and_Do_It_Well), in practice, it's very frustrating on a new user to try to troubleshoot something when you don't know where the tools are.

I find myself trying to troubleshoot Raspberry Pi networking quite often, and there are no GUI tools for the wired port, and it wasn't until Raspbian Jessie rolled out that there were GUI tools for the wifi.

Are there any (or one) GUI tools to do basic tasks related to networking for all adapters, similar in concept to how you can do things in Windows, Mac OS, Android, iOS, etc?

- View IP address
- Set static IP address
- Set static DNS information
- View/edit hostname
- View DHCP status
- Release/renew DHCP

What is maddening is that Raspbian Jessie's new tool looks like it will do some stuff for the wired adapter, but the only thing I can get it to do is show me an IP address on a mouse over.

Comment: Uh? Linux distributions have been carrying NetworkManager GUIs for at least a decade, what's wrong with it?

Comment: There's a guy on the Pi forums that sums it up nicely "Do not judge Linux by thr Raspberry Pi". Thr mprr I play the more I presume to understand what he means. I don't even know why they bother with a GUI, I think it's only there for the IDEs for the kids to learn on. Everything else is CLI of every article you will ever find.

Comment: I'm trying to ask an obviously-stupid-because-I'm-not-familiar-with-Linux-question to actually get the answer.  If it's that obvious to you, please make a proper answer.  I don't know what to make of your comment, nor will the next person.

Comment: [NetworkManager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetworkManager) is the most common tool to manage network connections dynamically, and most desktop environments include a GUI for it (called “network configuration” or something similar). The statement that “ wasn't until Raspbian Jessie rolled out that there were GUI tools for the wifi” is plain wrong: these tools existed before the Pi. Are you using that GUI? Does it lack some feature that you want? (Maybe it does; I'm not very familiar with it and the features you're asking are somewhat unusual.) What desktop environment are you using anyway?

Comment: The built in desktop environment is LXDE and if there are GUI tools for networking, they are cleverly hidden. There are about a half dozen available GUI apps/programs available on the distro. Jessie ups that to about a dozen, including the individual apps of an office suite. It's bare bones, presumably on purpose.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15209/using-network-manager-for-wireless-vpn-management

Comment: If you're a Windows user and you want to analyze network problems, why don't you use Wireshark from Windows? Often, it's better to watch the real network traffic from outside instead of inside. Imagine a short circuit in the RJ45 connector. The Raspberry itself might log the outgoing traffic, although it is never received by anyone.

Comment: @Thomas No, that's not a duplicate, and Wireshark is not an option, nor even in the realm of what I was referring to in the OP.